# looking for free c++ cross platform GUI framework

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform

im looking for cross platform GUI for free for commercial project
( that means i can't give the code ) no GPL and i guess no LGPL 
what else its leaving me ? wxWidgets ? 
Thanks

Comment: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262298/windows-c-ui-technology

Comment: He needs a cross platform library. That question deals with Windows UI libraries, and the top voted answer suggests WTL.

Comment: re-check LGPL, it's very non-restrictive, and won't have any 'viral' effect on your own code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to avoid LGPL, [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) is probably the most feature-complete option.  It uses a derivitive of LGPL which is more flexible on the distribution.

However, LGPL is fine for use with commercial works.  The only restriction is that you need to link dynamically with the UI library, which is typically not an issue at all.

Using LGPL, you have many other options, including GTK, QT (as of 4.5), FLTK, etc.  Of these, QT is probably my personal favorite.

Comment: besides linking, LGPL requires that if you ship a modified library, you have to provide the sources to the modification.  still not an issue, since your application can still be as closed as you wish.

Comment: Yes.  But - if you're using a mature, full featured library, typically there's very little that needs to be modified in the library itself.  You are still free to subclass the library for customization, as long as the original library is unmodified.

Comment: I've never (as of yet) had to do anything other than a minor bug fix in the core library (which I submitted back to the library devs anyways, so I don't mind having to provide).

Answer (score 5):

You can ship a closed-source application that links to LGPL licensed libraries.